# What is the advantage of ECDSA over Schnorr signature?

Tags: dsa, schnorr-signature

As we know, the Schnorr signature enjoys the linearity property, which does not exist in ECDSA. It seems the Schnorr signature is more efficient and can bring more features than ECDSA. What is the advantage of ECDSA over the Schnorr signature? Will ECDSA gradually be replaced by the Schnorr signature (especially after that the Schnorr signature can be used in Bitcoin)?

Comment: [Performance of ECDSA, ECKCDSA and ECGDSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/57577/18298) (Last paragraph) Inversion-free alternative. May I interest you in the Schnorr-based EdDSA, which avoids inversions altogether for signing and verification, and is widely available in high-quality software running in constant time with defense against broken random number generators at signing time?

Comment: Schnorr signature doesn't need an inverse, ECDSA is vulnerable to tiny bias on the $k$. ECDSA is already replaced in many places to [deterministic ECDSA](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979) ( thanks to our bear)

Comment: So you mean there is indeed no advantage of ECDSA over Schnorr signature?

Comment: EdDSA is inversion-free, but Bitcoin/Ethereum does not support EdDSA.